# Data type to hold a path to a page

Tags: c#, types

So at the moment I am using a string to hold the path to a page in my menu. 
An example would be:

> "Cars page > Audi Page > Audi A3 Page"

So instead of storing this in a string, is there a better data type for this? or will I have to create my own to make it more strict so it has to follow this specific structure?

Comment: What makes you unhappy with `string` as a data type for this problem?

Comment: You can use likedlist to store each part of the menu in separate node as long as the menu is not multilevel

Comment: A Stack<T> could be another option depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stack`

```
Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();
stack.Push("Cars");
stack.Push("Audi");
stack.Push("Audi A3");
String.Join(" > ", stack.Select(x => String.Format("{0} Page", x)).ToArray()).Dump();
```

> Audi A3 Page > Audi Page > Cars Page